# "Program received signal SIGSEGV , Segmentation fault” When trying to get all keywords of 3-character combinations using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault, cs50

I am trying to get all keywords of 3 characters using recursion but after some calls maybe call stack is full and the program crash with segmentation fault error , Code :

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void three_Characters(char c, char c2, char c3);

int main(void){
    three_Characters('A', 'A', 'A');
    return 0;
}

void three_Characters(char c, char c2, char c3){

//print 3-characters 
    printf("%c%c%c - ", c, c2, c3);

    /*Recursion termination*/
    if(c == 'z' && c2 == 'z' && c3 == 'z'){
        return;
    }

    /*Avoid symbol characters */
    if(c3 == 'Z'){
        c3 += 6;
        if(c2 == 'Z'){
            c2 += 7;
            if(c == 'Z'){
            c += 7;
            }
        }
    }

    if(c3 == 'z'){
        if(c2 == 'z'){
            c += 1;   c2 = 65;   c3 = 64;
        }else{
            c2 += 1;  c3 = 64;
        }
    }
    three_Characters(c, c2, c3 + 1); 
}
```

Comment: It seems you've chosen a complicated (and expensive) way to do this. Is recursing on each combination a given requirement? - because you can do it much more efficiently with loops.

Comment: loops are efficient with 3-character keywords but with 4 or 5 characters it takes a long time so i am trying to find an efficient solution using recursion

Comment: What makes you think that recursion is more efficient than a loop? Do you believe in magic?

Comment: You mean that iterative and recursive methods will take the same time as they will generate the same number of combinations ?

Comment: recursive methods take much longer as there is a lot of stack, register, etc manipulation that is not present in the iterative method

Comment: You have the special case of [tail recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). This is the most simple case to turn it into a loop. ;-) I've heart that modern compilers may even do it automatically (as optimization).

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried it with and without recursion on ideone. The funny fact - both versions run until `- EGC` and then die with runtime error. I looked up and down in your source but have not the slightest clue why the loop version dies as well. I thought it could be simply a timeout of online compiler but at the exactly same values of `c`, `c2`, `c3`?!? To get an idea, I tried the loop variant on wandbox.org as well and got `File size limit exceeded` after `MtT - MtU - Mt`. So, may be, it's rather a "spaceout" (instead of "timeout") on ideone.com as well.

Comment: The link of your sample code with recursion turned into an iteration: [**Live Demo on ideone**](https://ideone.com/Heu2fp). The change was minimal - 1 line excluded, 3 lines added. (And, I removed the `#include <cs50.h>` - it wasn't necessary.) I remarked the resp. lines with comments.

Comment: Yet another hint: If you do benchmarking at home (to find out which one is faster), please, don't forget to compile with `-O2`. ;-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, I copied your original sample (without `#include <cs50.h>`) to godbolt. Without optimization, you can see the recursive call at the bottom: `call three_Characters` ... `ret`. Using `-O2` instead, there is only one `call three_Characters` and only one `ret` at all, and both after `main:`. Instead, there appears a `jmp     three_Characters` for the recursive call. So, this makes me sure that `gcc 8.2 -O2` is really able to optimize tail recursion to an iteration. (The link: [**godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Ed7yHL).)

Comment: I didn't dig deeper (I'm no asm expert) but I wouldn't wonder if the optimized version hasn't anymore the **stack overflow** issue... :-)

Comment: Unrelated, but your code jumps from `AZZ` to `Aaa` instead of `AZa`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How deep do you expect your recursion to run?

You will get 52 levels iterating the last character from 'A... Za...z', 52*52 levels iterating over the last two characters, and 52*52*52 total recursion depth.

That's a recursion that is 140608 levels deep.

Every time you call a routine, you use some amount of stack. A return address must be saved. Often some registers must be saved as well.

On a 64-bit system, without optimization, it is likely that at least 32 bytes of stack will be used for *each* recursion level. That's 4499456 bytes. The stack limit on Linux is often 8MB, so you shouldn't run out of stack (and your program does not crash for me in either 64 or 32-bit mode). But you'll be using more than half of your available stack.

Your system probably has a lower stack limit (perhaps 4MB). If so, your program *will* run out of stack.

On Linux (and other UNIX OSes), use `ulimit -s` to find out what your current stack limit is, and `ulimit -s unlimited` to remove the stack limit (this should also allow your program to run to completion without hitting `SIGSEGV`).

P.S. Using recursion for this trivially iterable problem is *ill*-advised, precisely because you will use a *lot* of stack space.